# Horizontally align three elements on center, left and right in the same row/line

Tags: html, css, alignment

We have one container with three child elements:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-a">some content</div>
  <div class="box-b">other content</div>
  <div class="box-c">some other content</div>
</div>
```

We want to avoid using floats, and we'd like to align `box-a` on the `left` part of the page, `box-b` on the `center`, and `box-c` on the `right` part of the page.

All three child elements could have some padding/margin and a background color.

So far, we've used display: inline-block, but as the text-align should be set in the "container" element, we can only choose one method of alignment.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNwLJK here's how it looks

Comment: divs naturally want to expand to fill the entire line. if you want them all on the same line, then you'd have to width-limit them, or use spans instead, or switch to display:inline-block, blah blah blah

Comment: I added more clarifications . Display inline-block works fine but not when you wanna combine methods of alignment

Comment: Downvoters : Please elaborate

Comment: once you use floats, you have to use them everywhere...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `inline-block` porperty and also the `text-align` with the value `justify`. Try this:

```
.container {
    text-align:justify;
}
.container > div {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

But in order to make it work you need a little fix with a pseudo-element:

```
.container:after {
    content:" ";
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
```

**<kbd>Check the Snippet Below</kbd>**

```css
.container {
  text-align: justify;
}
.container > div {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.container:after {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-a">some content</div>
  <div class="box-b">other content</div>
  <div class="box-c">some other content</div>
</div>
```

---

<sub>**Note:** you need to have an empty space between the inline-block elements on the HTML markup, otherwise this won't work. Some builders/CMS systems minify the HTML so this makes all three elements count as one word therefore text-align justify doesn't work.</sub>

Comment: you rock; what's the logic behind the :after "fix"?

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos justify property makes the last line of text align left ... so with the fix we force the after element be the last-line making the other elements like content justify to the entire width

Comment: There weird thing is, although I am using the exact same CSS for my real-life use case, it doesn't work. The elements align left instead.

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos if you can reproduce your code on jsfiddle or codepen ... Then I can inspect and help you :)

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos you break my head XD .. The problem was it was displaying the form and the lsit as a single word ... with a space between the div and the form it takes like two words just fix that way http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPzrgN

Comment: .. oh man, I spent hours trying to figure this out! Maybe using floats would've been better to begin with. Many thanks!